# Call a method in a dynamically loaded module perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am using [Module::Load](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Load/) to load a module dynamically.
But I am not able to invoke a method defined in the module. Here is what I am doing

```
my $module = load("Module");
$module->function();
```

I am getting the following error:

Can't call method "function" without a package or object reference

What is wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `load` function doesn't have a specified return value. I think you're looking for this:

```
my $module = 'Module';
load($module);
$module->function();
```